# Cronjob sometimes fails to execute parts of the SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, cron

Okay so i tested a cronjob which will run on my site, but it seems that it sometimes fails to insert new data...

Basically i find which car from each category won the most versus battles and insert that data into a table which i use to display yesterdays winners..

Cron

```
0 0 * * *
```

Php code to be executed

```
$arr;
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" SELECT cars_versus_identifier, cars_versus_source, cars_versus_battles, cars_versus_won, cars_versus_category FROM cars_versus ");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($identifier, $imageSource, $battles, $won, $category);
$winners = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $arr[] = array('category' => $category, 'id' => $identifier, 'versus' => $versus, 'won' => $won);
     if(isset($winners[$category])) {
          $curmax = $winners[$category]['won'];
          if($won > $curmax) {
                $winners[$category] = array('id' => $identifier, 'won' => $won);
          }
     } else {

         $winners[$category] = array('id' => $identifier, 'won' => $won, 'imageSource' => $imageSource);
    }
}
$stmt->close();
print_r($winners);

$stmt = $dbCon->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE cars_winners");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

It is this part of the script that sometimes fails

```
foreach($winners as $key => $value){
    $id = $winners[$key]['id'];
    $imageSource = $winners[$key]['imageSource'];


    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" UPDATE cars_car "
            . " SET cars_car_versus = cars_car_versus + 1 "
            . " WHERE cars_car_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Success Versus <br>";
    } else {
        echo "Failed Versus <br>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    ////////////////////////////////
    //THIS PART IS SOMETIMES FAILING
    ////////////////////////////////
    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" INSERT INTO cars_winners (cars_winners_source) "
            . " VALUES (?) ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $imageSource);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Success Versus winners <br>";
    } else {
        echo "Failed Versus winners <br>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

$stmt = $dbCon->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE cars_versus");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

This is a critical part of my website which must not fail, what can i do to prevent it from failing?

I noted something strange, if i just run the cronjob without voting any of the images it will success every time.. but if i rate the daily cars through it will usualy fail one or two of the SQL querys in the foreach loop

Image of success
[image]

Image of sometimes when it fails (all of them failed this time)
[image]

Comment: how frequent you are running your cron.

Comment: Once every 24th hour at midnight

Comment: define "fails". what error do you get ? Try to append $dbCon->errorInfo() to "failed" message like:

echo "Failed Versus winners <br>"; print_r($dbCon->errorInfo());

This should give you better idea why it fails.

Comment: Will this work on prepared statement?

Comment: also, your bindparam looks strange. You used nameless parameter ? in sql, but 's' to bind it. It should be 1 (the order it appears in sql) if you are not using named parameters as far as I remember.

Comment: It is the order it appears in the SQL? isent it? or is there something i cant see here.

Also the error ->errorInfo() does not seem to work
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo() in /var/www/rateababe.com/public_html/shuffle.php:80 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/rateababe.com/public_html/shuffle.php on line 80

Comment: I get this error when i use print_r($stmt->error).. Column 'cars_winners_source' cannot be null... but why is this only happening sometimes?

Comment: I thought your dbcon was PDO. for mysqli instead of print_r($dbCon->errorInfo()), you should write: echo mysqli_error($dbCon);